# Build failed: Could not find an option named "track-widget-creation"

Tags: ios, xcode, visual-studio-code, flutter

I'm trying to build my project to deploy to TestFlight, but my build is failing whether using Xcode, terminal or vscode with the following error: Could not find an option named "track-widget-creation".

I have followed previous advice to fix this issue and unfortunately it doesn't work for me.

1. flutter clean
2. flutter build iOS --release

Xcode's output:
↳
    === BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===
    Could not find an option named "track-widget-creation".

```
Run 'flutter -h' (or 'flutter <command> -h') for available flutter commands and options.
Failed to build /Users/XXXXXX/Documents/Flutter/XXXXXX.
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 255
```

Comment: Have you check the issues on Github? There are other advices that you can try.
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/24239#issuecomment-460578875

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/26279

Comment: @mirkancal Thank you for the link. This fixed my issue 

Comment: I'm glad. Do you mind answering your own question and explain what you've applied to fix it, to inform others that might face the same issue in the future?

Comment: @mirkancal He minds.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by a amending the xcode_backend.sh file.

```
$FLUTTER_ROOT/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh

local track_widget_creation_flag=""
if [[ -n "$TRACK_WIDGET_CREATION" 

&& "${build_mode}" == "debug"

 ]]; then
  track_widget_creation_flag="--track-widget-creation"
fi
```